# How to shorten Gradle dependency cache folder names?

Tags: java, caching, intellij-idea, gradle

Is there a way to configure Gradle to shorten the folder names of its cached dependencies?
From [the Gradle user guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) it does not appear its possible, but figured to check with others.

My use case is because using the 'idea' Gradle plugin it helps with settings up Module dependencies. A problem arises when the Module classpath becomes 'too long' for cmd.exe (I'm not trying to discuss these limitations). Idea loads the project just fine, but its unable to run my program since it states the classpath is too long.

Since this is not an Idea problem, I figured it would be lovely if there was a way Gradle could cache deps using shorter folder names.

```
Example
from:         C:\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2\com.google.application\application\2.0\SVABNSAVSASAMNVSMAVSASN\application.jar
Options 1 To: C:\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2\c.g.a\a\2.0\SVABNSAVSASAMNVSMAVSASN\application.jar
Options 2 To: C:\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2\co.go.ap\ap\2.0\[tinyurl-equivalent]\application.jar
Options 3 To: C:\.g\c\m-2\f-2\c.g.a\a\2.0\[tinyurl-equivalent]\application.jar
Options 4 To: C:\.g\[tinyurl-equivalent]\application.jar
```

I do know that Idea does recognize the long classpath and prompts to enabled Dynamic Classpaths, but this has been known to cause other problems (some invoked apps cannot see the full classpath) and therefore I'd like to avoid this Idea option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Gradle 2.1, shortening dependency cache paths isn't supported. There are ideas around symlinking or copying dependencies into the project, but nothing concrete has materialized.